# How to authenticate from command line with redis-cli?

Tags: caching, redis

Till now am using below command to remove all keys which follows some pattern

```
redis-cli --raw keys "abc*" | xargs redis-cli del
```

but recently we decided to add password for our redis server , so in one environment i added password for redis server , and then when i try to execute the above command to remove keys , it is not working , do i need to use password in the above command ? how to use password in the above command ?

Comment: Type redis-cli --help and read the output

Comment: You should use the `--scan` option or `redis-cli` and not the `keys` command. And use the `-L` xargs option to batch the del to group of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify -a followed by your password.

> redis-cli -a yourpwd [plus other commands, see full example below]

You can pass multiple keys to one call of [DEL command](https://redis.io/commands/del) (`DEL key1 key2 key3 ... keyN`). Regarding setting of the password when calling `redis-cli` - you need to use `-a` option:

```
Usage: redis-cli [OPTIONS] [cmd [arg [arg ...]]]
...
-a       Password to use when connecting to the server.
```

Thus your final call can look like this:
`redis-cli -a PASS --raw keys "abc*" | xargs redis-cli -a PASS del`